# Select List item default value

Tags: oracle-apex

I have Select List item based on List of Values (Shared Components). As default value is null and there is problem, I have another Select List item based on SQL Query which one uses value of first Select List. Cascading List of Values not helping. How I can set first Select List value as first value by default? Clientside value is not null, but serverside is. Exactly I can change Source of first Select List item, but I don't want use the same query which one I use in List of Values from Shared Component. Page submit or item submit in Dynamic Actions is slow and user see that. Are there any other solutions?

P.S: For example first Select List displays Countries, second Select List displays cities. In my case when first Select List is null, second Select List displays all cities from all contries, I don't want this, I want to make first Select List without null value and second Select List with values (cities) by value from first Select List (country, not null).

In one of application page it works like I need, but I can't understand how, and I can't find the difference in code. In page where it works session page displays item value (Page Items, Session State), in another isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set "Display NULL value" to "No", it will show the first value of the select list

Comment: Display Null Value is disabled, and Item values is correct. Clientside value is okey, but serverside is null, because is not setted. I think problem is in "Source" because type NULL when value in session state is null, per user (disk), but in other page code is same, and it works.

Comment: "don't want use the same query which one I use in List of Values from Shared Component." ... I'm not sure there is another option. Calculate the initial value in a computation or a page process or as "default" option for the item.

Comment: But in another page is works like I need and difference that in "Session" page "Page Items" and "Session State" displaying Select List item, in another page is not (same after submit).

Comment: Does this page item belong to a form region ? If so, make sure the attribute "Source > Maintain session state" is set to "Per Session"

Comment: All items of two pages in Static Content regions.

Comment: I have no other ideas... without seeing your app it is hard. I suggest you turn on debug for the working and non-working page and study the difference, maybe there is a clue there

Comment: My mistake about another page where is "Okey". Same problem. By default all Select Lists values is NULL, "Items to Submit" in my case works only with Charts, in SQL Query or other Regions isn't work. Solution is as you said, set the default value in Source/Default/Computation or etc. But is not convenient for lists where is dynamic values, because for display, in my case, I using List Of Values from Shared Component, then I must use same query from Shared Components, maybe better is add null value with name for example "Select value" and after select submit the page.

Comment: But still I can't understand, why in one page in "Session" display item value (Page Items, Session State), and another isn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224631/discussion-between-koen-lostrie-and-es).